# How to find out what my unhandled exception is

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

This is probably the dumbest question ever, but i have absolutely no idea what an exception i am getting is, all i know is i'm getting one and google doesn't want to let me know why.

Here is what it says:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function draw at 0x02A403B0>
```

And this is what caused it, although it'd be nice if somebody could tell me what is up with my bad code, i'd also quite like to know how i can find out myself next time this happens, since this happens so much.

```
def draw():
    while True:
        for x in range(0,10):
            for y in range (0,10):
                if (coord[x][y] == 0):
                    canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="white")
                if (coord[x][y] == 1):
                    canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="red")
                if (coord[x][y] == 2):
                    canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="darkorange")
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Comment: You can't run tkinter functions in a thread other than the thread that is running `mainloop`.

Comment: I don't see any end to that `while True` and did you mean for the sleep to be inside the while?

Comment: @BryanOakley Is it not possible for me to constantly update the rectangles in that way as well as run the mainloop?

Comment: @Endophage Yes, it is supposed to constantly draw rectangles in a 10x10 grid based on the number in the 2D array, and the sleep is so that the updates per second don't overload the CPU

Comment: @Eykar: it is not possible to update the triangles from another thread. The normal way to do it is to create a function that does one update of the display, then have that function use `after` to call itself every few milliseconds. Remove the `while True:` statement, then add `canvas.after(30, draw)`. Once you call `draw` once, it will continue to call itself every 30 milliseconds.

Comment: @BryanOakley Great, thanks, this worked perfectly! Although uses a lot of the CPU

Comment: @Eykar: you can always have it run less frequently. Change the 30 to 60 and it should use about half as much CPU.

Comment: @Eykar so I say again, shouldn't the `sleep` be **inside** the `while` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For debugging only, I would enclose the whole thing in a `try-except` printing the exception and re-raising it:

```
def draw():
    try:
        while True:
            for x in range(0,10):
                for y in range (0,10):
                    if (coord[i][j] == 0):
                        canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="white")
                    if (coord[i][j] == 1):
                        canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="red")
                    if (coord[i][j] == 2):
                        canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50, fill="darkorange")
        time.sleep(0.03)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect :D
It turns out exception #1 was that i was using coord[i][j] when i was using x and y. oops.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter objects can't be called from any thread other than the one where mainloop is running. Instead, you should remove the use of threads, and remove the use of the infinite loop. Instead, do something like this (though, I don't know where i and j are coming from, I'm just copying your code...):

```
def draw():
    for x in range(0,10):
        for y in range (0,10):
            item = canvas.create_rectangle((x * 40) + 10, (y * 40) + 10, 
                                           (x * 40) + 50, (y * 40) + 50)
            if (coord[i][j] == 0):
                canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="white")
            if (coord[i][j] == 1):
                canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="red")
            if (coord[i][j] == 2):
                canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="darkorange")
    canvas.after(30, draw)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you already have an infinite loop running -- the event loop. Every iteration of the event loop (or more accurately, every 30 milliseconds in the event loop) you call draw.

This code looks like it will be a real memory hog, however. Do you really intend to continue to create new rectangles every 30 milliseconds? Eventually you'll have performance problems since you'll end up with hundreds of thousands of overlapping rectangles.

Comment: i and j are mistakes, i wanted to use x and y since i was dealing with coordinates and the i and j in the coord list are a force of habit.

And yeah, i just left it running by accident for a couple of minutes and my computer wasn't happy about it, i didn't know about canvas.itemconfig() before so i'm guessing after i create all 100 rectangles i can use this to simply change the colours.

I must sleep now, i'll try this out tomorrow :)

Comment: ok, i've only just got around to doing this, why is this any more efficient than the previous method? Doesn't it still create 100 rectangles every 30 milliseconds

Comment: @Eykar: yes, it still creates all those rectangles. The point was to illustrate the proper way to draw in intervals without causing the GUI to sleep. I had no way of knowing if you needed to create all those rectangles or not.